# SynchronizationContext is null in OnStart method of WindowsService

Tags: c#, windows-services, task-parallel-library, synchronizationcontext

I am trying to create a background Task for my windows service (it is already installed via InstallUtil.exe) and use **SynchronizationContext** to send some messages to the main Service thread.

Unfortunately `SynchronizationContext.Current` is always `null` on service start.

I've saw some questions around the topic and hints on why SynchronizationContext is null in various scenarios (e.g. in Winforms, WPF apps) but no clue about the Windows services.

How can I resolve this issue? 
Below the code:

```
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SnmpTrapListenerService
{
    public partial class SnmpTrapListenerService : ServiceBase
    {
        public Listener Listener { get; set; }
        public CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }
        public Task PulseTask { get; set; }
        public SynchronizationContext SyncContext { get; set; }

        public SnmpTrapListenerService()
        {
            //Debugging windows service.  
            Debugger.Launch();
            InitializeComponent();
            Debug.WriteLine($"Main service threadId: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                SyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current; //Here I'm getting always null.
                PulseTask = new Task(x =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Pulse task threadId: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var context = (SynchronizationContext)x;
                        context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(y => DoSomethingOnServiceMainThread()), null);
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Alive at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    }
                }, SyncContext, CancellationTokenSource.Token);

                PulseTask.Start();

                Listener = new Listener();
                Listener.AddBinding(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 162)); //IP address of listener system  
                Listener.MessageReceived += Listener_MessageReceived;
                Listener.StartAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Service started");
        }
        private static void Listener_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("servicelog.log", "Version :" + e.Message.Version + "\n");
            File.AppendAllText("servicelog.log", "Version :" + e.Message.Scope.Pdu.Variables[4].Data.ToString() + "\n");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            Listener.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine("Service stopped");
        }

        private void DoSomethingOnServiceMainThread() 
        {
            //Some work that needs to be done one Service main thread.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "main service thread". It's up to you to start your own threads in a service.

Comment: By "main service thread" I mean that one in which ctor of the Service class and OnStart/OnStop methods are invoked.

Comment: That thread isn't there for you to use. It calls OnStart, and OnStop, and you have a certain number of seconds to return. Otherwise, you can't use that thread.

Comment: Here you have a proof that it is running all the time. On the top you have the output that returns the thread id and below you've got the THREADS windows after ~20 mins. https://imgur.com/sB1ycdN

Comment: I'm not sure why you're arguing so hard? The way to write a service is to start your own threads as necessary in OnStart - that is the way that it's done. The thread that calls OnStart does not have a SynchronizationContext installed on it (as you noticed), and there's almost certainly no way for you to post a message to it - I've no idea whether it's even running a message pump! Services aren't like UI applications, where the UI controls have affinity to the main thread.

Comment: As others have said, that's *not* your thread. It's not there for you to use. It's actually used to service interactions between your service and the service control manager.

Comment: @canton7 I'm not arguing. Just wanted to understand how things works in that configuration. Being curious and thinking in "what ifs" and "how abouts" are things that we suppose to do as devs sometimes right? I was just giving you inputs from IDE for a reference. Now I get the concept. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Console and Service applications do not have a default SynchronizationContext.  This is because there is no "UI" thread that is pumping messages constantly while the application runs.

The question is why do you need a synchronization context?